# Relate/combine 2 different xpath Java Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

This url will show the search result of a product in Amazon site.
https://www.amazon.com/s?k=yellow+puma+shoes&s=price-asc-rank&qid=1559364287&ref=sr_st_price-asc-rank

Using this xpath I can get product name

```
//span[@class='a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal']
```

Using this xpath I can get price

```
//span[@class='a-offscreen']
```

Is there a way to combine these 2 so that I can relate product name with price. 1 Way I can think of is:

//span[@class='a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal']

```
List<WebElements> allProductNames**** Save them in a list. Then run a for loop

for()
{
text = getText
//span[text()='PUMA Mens Basket Classic']/../../../../../..//span[@class='a-offscreen']
}
```

If you have an idea for easier solution kindly suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather get all the items and then iterate through each of them with in a loop as shown below.

```
    // get all products
    List<WebElement> products = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@data-component-type='s-search-results']//div[@class='sg-row'][2]"));
    // create a map (consider it as dictionary that  to hold key value pair) to hold product and price
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (WebElement product : products) {
        String item = "";
        String price = "";
        // get product name
        item = product.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@class='a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal']")).getText();
        // get product price (some products have range so we have to get the prices and display)
        List<WebElement> prices = product.findElements(By.xpath(".//span[@class='a-offscreen']"));
        for (WebElement pPrice : prices) {
            if (price !=""){
                price = price + "-" + pPrice.getAttribute("textContent");
            }else {
                price = pPrice.getAttribute("textContent");
            }
        }
        // push the product and price to the map
        map.put(item, price);

    }
    System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: If I understand correctly this is what you did: 1) in products list you saved all the information(price, name, review etc) 2) In the HashMap add item and price. Why the item is not a list but price is. I thought that item had to be a list as well. Thanks.

Comment: I see, because if it was a list then you would not be able to use the getText() to save as String.